# Can you fix "cl.exe failed with exit status 2"

Tags: visual-studio-2019

```
<CL Condition="'%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeader)' != 'Create' and '%(ClCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true' and '%(ClCompile.CompilerIteration)' == '' and @(ClCompile) != ''"
```

When I click, got  `"cl.exe failed with exit status (code 2)"`

Comment: <CL Condition="'%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeader)' != 'Create' and '%(ClCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true' and '%(ClCompile.CompilerIteration)' == '' and @(ClCompile) != ''"

Comment: I clicked "cl.exe failed with exit status (code 2)"

Comment: please help me..

Comment: Please place all the code and error message in the question itself, it will make it easier to read and answer. You can use the `edit` button to do that, and make sure the use block quotes around your code (select the code and click on the `{}` button).

Comment: It is a pretty annoying bug in VS2019.  They'll fix it, eventually, just focus on the other error messages you got.  Fix those and this error should disappear as well.